# ONVIF Camera change snapshot resolution (getSnaphotUri)

Tags: python, onvif, python-onvif

I'm using python-onvif to find the URI of my camera to get a static snapshot.  And it works fine, I can get the snapshot.

But the resolution is not at the 'full' 720 which my camera can acheive. And does get when streaming.  The snapshot is only like 640x352 or something.

How can I tell ONVIF to take the snapshot with full resolution?

I tried generating the URI using getSnapshotUri(token) and putting in the token of the main profile with the highest resolution, but I get the same URI and same resolution.

Is there a way to get a full resolution snapshot?

The docs say it will use the jpeg settings "from the profile" but I can't figure out how to tell it which profile, or what resolution settings to use.

I'm not sure code is really needed in this case, but here is what I'm doing anyway. In case it helps someone

```
 from onvif import ONVIFCamera

 # Set up the camera object using the ONVIF port.
 mycam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.2.111', 8080, 'admin', 'pass', '/etc/onvif/wsdl/')


 #access media service
 media = mycam.create_media_service()                

 allProfiles = media.GetProfiles()
 mainProfile = media.GetProfile({'ProfileToken' : allProfiles[0]._token})

 snapshot = media.GetSnapshotUri({'ProfileToken' : mainProfile._token})

 print 'My Cam: ' + str(snapshot)
```

*****Update 20160412

Here is some more information as requested.

I ran the following

```
for p in media.GetVideoEncoderConfigurations():
    print p
```

And I get the following printed out which was long so I put it in a pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/Wfe4CPLy

Nothing about JPEG is available. H264 resolution is there, so I know the camera can do video at higher resolution. But the getsnapshot uri still only has a lower resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The snapshot resolution is configured by the JPEG video encoder.
In the [media.wsdl](http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/media.wsdl) embedded documentation it is written :

> **GetSnapshotUri**
>   Description:A client uses the GetSnapshotUri command to obtain a JPEG snapshot from the device. [...].
>   The URI can be used for acquiring a JPEG image through
>   a HTTP GET operation. The image encoding will always be JPEG
>   regardless of the encoding setting in the media profile. The Jpeg
>   settings (like resolution or quality) may be taken from the profile if
>   suitable. The provided image will be updated automatically and
>   independent from calls to GetSnapshotUri.

In order to modify the resolution of JPEG encoder you can proceed like this:

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

# Set up the camera object using the ONVIF port.
mycam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.2.111', 8080, 'admin', 'pass')

#access media service
media = mycam.create_media_service()                

# iterate on encoder configurations
for p in media.GetVideoEncoderConfigurations():
    if p.Encoding == "JPEG":
        print 'JPEG Encoder:' + p._token

        # get encoder options    
        options = media.GetVideoEncoderConfigurationOptions({'ConfigurationToken':p._token})
        print options.JPEG.ResolutionsAvailable

        # get encoder configuration
        cfg = media.GetVideoEncoderConfiguration({'ConfigurationToken':p._token})

        # select the resolution  
        cfg.Resolution = options.JPEG.ResolutionsAvailable[0]

        # update the encoder configuration
        request = media.create_type('SetVideoEncoderConfiguration')
        request.Configuration = cfg
        request.ForcePersistence = True
        media.SetVideoEncoderConfiguration(request)
```

Depending on the camera capacities some combinaison between encoders configuration could be not possible.

Comment: When I do the 'for' loop, the p.Encoding always returns 'H264' and never has a 'JPEG'.  Does that mean this cheap camera doesn't have JPEG encoder? The 'H264' has the ability to do 1280x720, so I feel like I should be able to get a full res JPEG somehow. But p.Encoding never == 'JPEG' and does nothing.

Comment: I don't know why ONVIF forum did not add resolution argument in the `GetSnaptshotUri` ? This seems the "natural" way to ask for a specific resolution. By the way, Is there some JPEG options in the H264 encoder configuration ?

Comment: I updated my question with all the encoder options. But basically no, there are no JPEG options anywhere that I can see.

Comment: I was wondering if the `GetVideoEncoderConfigurationOptions` return some JPEG resolutions (including the 640x352 resolution you get).